# Is the following syntax in my robots.txt file, blocking all crawlers from indexing my site?

Tags: web-crawler

This is currently in my robots.txt file:

User-agent: * # Disallow everyone else
Disallow: /

Question-to me, the novice here, it looks like the "Disallow: /" will prevent Google/MSN/etc from indexing my site.  Correct?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax of the robots.txt file for your purpose seems to be as follows:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /